# Dynamic Form Input with Select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

Trying my hand on dynamic form fields with itemz[].

I would like the form fields duplicate and have the select populate from the json object.

```
   <!-- DYNAMIX ITEMS-->
                               <div class='container1'> 
                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <select id='itemz' name='itemz[]' class='itemz'>    </select>

                                                        </td>   
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='count[]' value=''>
                                                            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='weight[]' value='<?= $items['weight']; ?> '>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <!-- ADD MORE -->
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button class='add_form_field'>Add More</button>
                                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                             </div>
```

Here is the JS that is suppose to:
1) populate the drop down
but it only populates the first box, I tried using a for each on the class but no luck.

2) Duplicates the dropdown, but instead of appending after it adds it before the first main div

```
      <script>
// POPULATING THE DROP DOWN
var obj={
Prod: 
<?php echo $products; ?>

};

  for(var i=0;i<obj.Prod.length;i++)
{
  var option=$('<option></option>').text(obj.Prod[i]['item']);
    $( ".itemz" ).append(option);
}

 // DUPLICATING THE DROP DOWNS         
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $(".container1"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $(".add_form_field"); //Add button ID

    var x = 1; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();

        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment
            $(wrapper).append("<tr><td><select id='itemz' name='itemz[]' class='itemz'></select></td>   <td><input class='form-control' type='text' name='count[]' value=''><input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='weight[]' value=''> </td> <td><a href='#' class='remove_field'>Remove</a> </td></tr></div>"); //add input box
        }
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});

      </script>
```

Here is my JSON object:

```
Prod: 
[{"id":"1","item":"Piano","weight":"200"},{"id":"2","item":"Fridge","weight":"50"},{"id":"3","item":"Freezer","weight":"100"},{"id":"4","item":"Sofa","weight":"20"},{"id":"5","item":"Microwave","weight":"10"},{"id":"6","item":"Dining Table","weight":"40"},{"id":"7","item":"Coffee Table","weight":"20"}]   
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var obj={
      Prod:[
      {
       "id":"1",
       "item":"Piano",
       "weight":"200"
      },{
       "id":"2",
       "item":"Fridge",
       "weight":"50"
      },{
       "id":"3",
       "item":"Freezer",
       "weight":"100"
      },{
       "id":"4",
       "item":"Sofa",
       "weight":"20"
      },{
       "id":"5",
       "item":"Microwave",
       "weight":"10"
      },{
       "id":"6",
       "item":"Dining Table",
       "weight":"40"
      },{
       "id":"7",
       "item":"Coffee Table",
       "weight":"20"
      }
      ]
};



var max_fields= 10;
var curent_fields=0;

function add_options(_el){
  for(var key in obj.Prod){
    var text=obj.Prod[key].item;
    var id=obj.Prod[key].id;
    var weight=obj.Prod[key].weight;
    var el =$('<option/>').text(text).val(id).attr('weight',weight);
    $(_el).append(el);
  }
}

function add_controls(){
    if(curent_fields>=max_fields){
     alert('max feilds '+max_fields);
     return false;
    }
    $('.container1').append('<tr><td><select name="itemz[]" class="itemz"></select></td><td><input class="form-control" type="text" name="count[]" value=""><input class="form-control" type="hidden" name="weight[]" value=""><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="remove_field">Remove</a></td><td>');
    add_options($('.itemz').last());
    $('.itemz').last().change(function(){
         select_change(this);
 });
 $('.itemz').last().parent().next().find('.remove_field').click(function(){
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
    curent_fields--;
 });
 curent_fields++;
}

function select_change(_el){
        var curent_weight=$(_el).children(':selected').attr('weight');
        var curent_id=$(_el).children(':selected').val();
        var curent_item=$(_el).children(':selected').text();
          //set hidden feid value
        $(_el).parent().next().find('[name^="weight"]').val(curent_weight);
          //your more code...

        console.log([curent_id,curent_weight,curent_item]);
}

function start(){
 add_options($('.itemz').last());
    $('.itemz').last().change(function(){
         select_change(this);
 });
}

start();

$('.add_form_field').click(function(){
 add_controls();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



                          <div class='container1'>
                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <select id='itemz' name='itemz[]' class='itemz'>    </select>

                                                        </td>
                                                        <td>
                                                            <input class='form-control' type='text' name='count[]' value=''>
                                                            <input class='form-control' type='hidden' name='weight[]' value=''>
                                                        </td>

                                                        <!-- ADD MORE -->
                                                        <td>
                                                            <button class='add_form_field'>Add More</button>
                                                        </td>

                                    </tr>
                             </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, it does exactly what I was expecting. Kudos! I wish I had more knowledge about each part though